# Какая разница в typename и class в параметрах шаблона?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Я не совсем понимаю разницу между:

```
template <typename T>
```

и

```
template <class T>
```

Если она есть, то в чём заключается?

Comment: В этом контексте между `class` и `typename` нет никакой разницы.

Comment: С точки зрения компилятора разницы нет, а с точки зрения человека читающего код лушче писать typename, так как это ближе к истине.

Comment: Без разницы, самый обычный legacy, однако можно при помощи `class` намекнуть тому, кто будет использовать этот шаблон (или самому себе) на то, что скалярные типы по какой-либо причине нельзя/нежелательно использовать.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

В современном, т.е. C++17 варианте языка разницы между `class` и `typename` применительно к шаблонам нет. Однако, в более ранних стандартах разница была заметна при использовании шаблонных шаблонных (sic!) параметров, т.е. когда в качестве аргумента шаблона выступает шаблонный же тип. В этом случае использование `typename` перед именем шаблонного типа не являлось допустимым.

Пример шаблонной функции `f` (нужно раскомментировать только одну строку):

```
//template<template<typename> class C>    // любой с++ 
//template<template<class>    class C>    // любой с++ 
//template<template<class>    typename C> // начиная с c++17
//template<template<typename> typename C> // начиная с c++17
void f() { }
```

В случае указания современному компилятору использовать более старую версию стандарта [можем получить сообщение](https://wandbox.org/permlink/yhytX2n5wvrPPLcd) следующего вида:

> template template parameter using 'typename' is a C++17 extension [-Wc++17-extensions]

Упомянутое ограничение возникало из-за следующего определения синтаксиса при использовании шаблонных шаблонных параметров до c++17 (в частности в с++11 п.14.1/1):

> ```
> template < template-parameter-list > class ...opt identifieropt
> template < template-parameter-list > class identifieropt = id-expression
> ```

Здесь видно явное упоминание слова `class`.

В c++17 (черновик [N4687](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4687.pdf) п.17.1/1):

> ```
> template < template-parameter-list > type-parameter-key ...opt identifieropt
> template < template-parameter-list > type-parameter-key identifieropt = id-expression
> ```

явный `class` заменили на *type-parameter-key*, который разворачивается следующим образом ниже по тексту:

> ```
> type-parameter-key : 
>     class 
>     typename
> ```

Таким образом `typename` становится возможным использовать совместно с `class`.

Comment: Интересно, а зачем вообще изначально разрешили использовать `typename` в шаблонах? Использовали бы `class` и хватит.

Comment: @int3 вероятно, чтобы отразить ситуацию, когда типом может быть не класс, а например, какой-нибудь `int`.

Answer (score 13):

Стандарт C++ говорит следующее [п.14.1.2]:

> There is no semantic difference between class and typename in a
>   template-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Таким образом можно создать удобство записи, чтения и восприятия. Например:

```
template < class Cont >
void  show(const Cont& cont, std::ostream& out) {}
```

Тут сразу бросается в глаза, что аргумент это контейнерный класс, и функция скорее всего выводит в  `out` содержимое контейнера. Слово `template` в данном случаи для восприятия не так эффетивно. А вот:

```
template<typename Tp, typename Sequence = std::deque<Tp> >
class stack{};
```

Тут легче понять, что `Tp` это тип элементов стека, а `Sequence` атрибут реализации (в данном случаи создается его адаптер).